# How to connect my webservice with mysql on k8s?

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to deploy a webservice, which has to connect with Mysql. Everything is working when I run them on docker-compose but on **Kubernetes (Minikube)** I am getting these error: **dial tcp: lookup mysql on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host**. Any idea what I may be missing? Here are my manifest-files:

The webservice hast to be accessible over the internet and is listening on port 8080. Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: webservice-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: blur
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  type: NodePort
```

Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: blur-service
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: blur
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: blur
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: blur-service
        image: marjugoncalves/blur-service
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

The manifest-files of mysql:

Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: blur
  ports: 
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
```

Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: mysql
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: blur
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: blur
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mysql
        image: mysql:8.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
```

Comment: Also note that the Service `mysql-service` will connect to any Pod labeled with `app: blur`, which includes the Pods created by the Deployment `blur-service`.  You probably want more specific labels here so that the Service only selects the MySQL Pods.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, my friend!

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was my mistake: In my app, in the string used to connect to the database I used "mysql" as hostname so that the **service name** also has to be called like that. My service should look like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql //here was the mistake
spec:
  selector:
    app: blur
  ports: 
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
```